# Get the MailItem specific to the reply in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, mailitem

I'm making an Outlook plugin that needs to change several properties of a `MailItem` when the user clicks "reply" to any email.  I'm currently doing something like this:

```
Private Sub PrepareEmailForReply(ByVal MailItem As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal FromAddress As String)
    If Not ReplyDictionary.ContainsKey(MailItem.ConversationID) Then
        ReplyDictionary.Add(MailItem.ConversationID, FromAddress)
        AddHandler MailItem.Reply, Sub()
                                               InReply = True
                                   End Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CurrentExplorer_SelectionChange() Handles CurrentExplorer.SelectionChange
    Dim SelectedFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder
    Try
        If Me.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
            Dim SelectedObject As Object = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
            If (TypeOf SelectedObject Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
                Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(SelectedObject, Outlook.MailItem)

                If (CurrentEmail IsNot MailItem) Then
                    Output.AddInfo(MailItem.ConversationTopic)

                    CurrentEmail = MailItem
                    If (InReply) Then
                        Output.AddInfo("> In Reply")
                        If ReplyDictionary.ContainsKey(MailItem.ConversationID) Then
                            MailItem.Subject = "Testing Reply Email"
                        End If
                    Else
                        Output.AddInfo("> In MailItem")
                        For Each Recipient As Outlook.Recipient In MailItem.Recipients
                            Dim CurrentEmailAddress As String = Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress.ToLower.Trim()
                            If ListeningUsers.Contains(CurrentEmailAddress) Then
                                PrepareEmailForReply(MailItem, CurrentEmailAddress)
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    InReply = False
                End If
                End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Everything works fine, but the MailItem on the line that says `MailItem.Subject = "Testing Reply Email" doesn't actually correspond to the Reply email, so the subject doesn't get changed.

How do I get the MailItem for the reply email so that I can change the subject of it?

The `ListeningUsers` variable is a `List(of String)` that contains a list of what emails this is valid for.  It contains the current user.

**EDIT: **

This is where I've added a few changes to the MailItem.Reply event call:

```
        AddHandler MailItem.Reply, Sub()
                                       Dim CurrentInspector As Outlook.Inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()
                                       Dim ReplyMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(CurrentInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
                                       If (ReplyMailItem IsNot Nothing) Then
                                           MsgBox("1: " & ReplyMailItem.Subject & " - " & ReplyMailItem.EntryID)
                                           Return
                                       End If

                                       CurrentInspector = CurrentExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
                                       ReplyMailItem = TryCast(CurrentInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
                                       If (ReplyMailItem IsNot Nothing) Then
                                           MsgBox("2: " & ReplyMailItem.Subject & " - " & ReplyMailItem.EntryID)
                                       End If
                                   End Sub
```

The first `msgbox` will appear if I open an email in an external window and then click reply, however, if I click reply to an email inside of Outlook (not a popup window) then the second `msgbox` should appear, but it doesn't.

Comment: Need to use `ConversationId`/`ConversationIndex` to track related messages. What version of Outlook is this? Later versions (>2010) have very easy APIs for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yep!  This is from Outlook in Office 365.

Comment: Have a look at [`MailItem.GetConversation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869870%28v=office.15%29.aspx) From there, you have the whole [`Conversation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862527%28v=office.15%29.aspx) API.

Comment: So, using the Conversation API, how am I supposed to get the MailItem of the reply after the reply event fires?

Comment: So are you trying to get the mailItem of the reply email or are you trying to send a custom reply after you click the reply button?

Comment: Well, I need to just change the subject line / message / whatever else that I need to change of the current response.  I need to be able to click reply and then change the reply.  I don't think it's really a custom reply because I need everything the same - I just want to change the reply email as soon as it's made - I assume I would need to get the `mailitem` object of the reply and then change that, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the reply email is not an easy thing to do.  I've bugged the Outlook product team for many years now to include a ReplyItem property on the MailItem object but they haven't listened.

The problem is that the user can reply to a selected email OR an open email.  You can always monitor Inspectors.NewInspector and check for a blank MailItem.EntryID value for the new emails and ensure that MailItem.Recipients.Count > 0.  Then you'll know it's a reply, and then you'll have to get Explorer.Selection OR loop through Inspectors (to find open email windows).  Then you'll have to match ConversationID on the selected/open email with the new compose email.

Comment: So, using `Inspectors.NewInspector` I was able to easily get when it was opened up in the external mail windows, but is there no way to get it while it's inside of the selected email window that's inside of outlook?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that please? I'm not sure what you mean. I'm guessing, but if you mean the "active" window then you can reference that via Application.ActiveInspector.

Comment: Like, I could get the mailitem if the message was "popped out," but not if it was still inside of the main outlook window, not popped out.

Comment: Oh - for "Inline Replies", you need to get the MailItem from the Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231535%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hey, I went ahead and tried that, but was unable to get it to work.  It won't popup the second `msgbox` when a reply is made inside of the main outlook window.  I made an edit in my question to reflect this.

Comment: You need to capture the MailItem.Reply event for the inline message first.  The Response object argument for that event will supply the MailItem object for the new reply message.